# Subset of the $(x,y)$ plane satisfying $x^2 - xy + y^2 \le 0$

Tags: inequality, plane-geometry

The problem:

Describe and Illustrate the region in the $(x,y)$ plane satisfying $x^2 - xy + y^2 \le 0$.

My thoughts:

Write the inequality as $x^2 + y^2 \le xy$.

We can associate with a point (other than the origin) in the plane the right-triangle with hypotenuse its distance from the origin, and legs its projections onto the x and y axes. Then the inequality claims the square of the hypotenuse is less than or equal to the product of the other sides.

This cannot be true for any right triangle since the hypotenuse is greater than either side, so its square must be greater than the product of those sides. Thus the inequality is not satisfied for any point other than the origin.

So the only point where the inequality is satisifed is the origin. Is my reasoning correct?

Can someone please provide me with an algebraic proof so I can be more confident.

Comment: Hint: $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to the inequality $x^2-xy+y^2\leq 0$.

Comment: It's $ \{ (0,0) \}$.

Comment: Hint : $$(x-y/2)^2+3/4y^2=x^2-xy+y^2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2-xy+y^2=\frac{1}{2}(2x^2+2y^2-2xy)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2)\geq 0$$

with equality iff $$x=y=x-y=0$$

Your reasoning seems fine to me! You just need to be a bit careful where a triangle doesn't exist - i.e. one of the legs has length $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the inequality into
$$
x^2-2xy+y^2\le -xy
$$
but also into
$$
x^2+2xy+y^2\le 3xy
$$
Any solution must therefore satisfy $-xy\ge0$ and $xy\ge0$, because the left hand sides are respectively $(x-y)^2$ and $(x+y)^2$. This forces $xy=0$.

If $x=0$, then you need $y^2\le0$; if $y=0$, then you need $x^2\le0$.

Comment: Very cool solution. May I ask how one would think of it? Perhaps from noticing that expression on left of original inequality can be slightly tweaked to form $(x-y)^2$ and $(x+y)^2$ and so just exploring both of those and noticing the rest?

Comment: @trynalearn The idea is that a homogeneous polynomial in two variables is essentially the same as a polynomial in one variable, in this case $t^2-t+1$, which has negative discriminant, so it can only takes on positive values.

Comment: Interesting. How do I see that a homogenous polynomial in two variables is essentially the same as a polynomial in one variable? In this case you're saying that $x^2 - xy + y^2$ is essentially the same as $t^2 - t + 1$? How do I see this?

Comment: Ah I see you seem to have set $y$ = 1 and left $x$ the same?

Comment: @trynalearn Yes, that's one way. The other is to write the polynomial as $y^2((x/y)^2-(x/y)+1)$, for $y\ne0$. Anyway, after realizing the only solution is $(0,0)$, one just has to find an elegant proof. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

AM-GM:

$x^2+y^2 \ge 2|x||y$|, equality for $|x|=|y|$.

Hence:

$2|x||y| \le (x^2+y^2)  \le xy$, $x,y$, real,

implies $x=y=0$.